# Переход от процедурного стиля программирования к ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Изучаю ООП в PHP, просьба подсказать структуру классов или уже существующий скрипт с грамотным ООП, где можно посмотреть реализацию сходной  задачи.

Нужно обрабатывать товары, имеющие общие свойства: название, кол-во и цена, но некоторые товары обладают особыми свойствами (например: у одежды - размер, у ноутбука - процессор). У каждого свойства товара есть свои ограничения (упрощенно): название (^[а-я\s-]{3,50}$), кол-во (1-100), цена (0,01 - 10 000) и множество других. Также, в зависимости от прав пользователя, который редактирует товар, различаются и доступные для редактирования свойства. Например: менеджер может добавить/редактировать товар, указав его наименование (обязательно) и ссылку (не обязательно) а цену только видит (без возможности редактировать), бухгалтер - не имеет права на добавление, но может изменять цену существующего товара и его кол-во, но не наименование.

В процедурном стиле, это выглядит примерно так:

```
/** Настройки товаров */
$shop['item']['name']['type'] = 'string';
$shop['item']['name']['min_len'] = 3;
$shop['item']['name']['max_len'] = 50;
$shop['item']['name']['pattern'] = '~^[а-я\s-]{'.$shop['item']['name']['min_len'].','.$shop['item']['name']['max_len'] .'}$~ui';

$shop['item']['price']['type'] = 'float'; // В БД хранится как DECIMAL 
$shop['item']['price']['min_val'] = 0.01;
$shop['item']['price']['max_val'] = 10000;
//... Другие настройки

/** 
 * Настройки редактирования товаров 
 */
$shop['edit_type']['manager']['action'] = ['add', 'upd'];
$shop['edit_type']['manager']['field']['name']['action'] = 'change';
$shop['edit_type']['manager']['field']['name']['val'] = 'necessarilly';
$shop['edit_type']['manager']['field']['url']['action'] = 'change';
$shop['edit_type']['manager']['field']['url']['val'] = 'optional';
// ...
$shop['edit_type']['buch']['action'] = ['upd'];
$shop['edit_type']['buch']['field']['price']['action'] = 'change';
$shop['edit_type']['buch']['field']['price']['val'] = 'necessarilly';
$shop['edit_type']['buch']['field']['name']['action'] = 'view';
```

Далее пишутся функции, которые в зависимости от параметров массива $shop['edit_type'] выводят формы добавления/редактирования и проверяют введенные данные (+ на каждый тип свойства товара своя функция, использующая данные $shop['item']).

Подскажите схему построения классов/трейтов/и.т.п для реализации задачи с помощью ООП? На сколько себе представляю я - все настройки ($shop['item'], $shop['edit_type']) хранятся в трейте(ах), чтобы их можно было использовать в различных объектах классов, отдельные классы для проверки данных и для вывода?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю написать класс, в котором имеется массив всех товаров, которые в свою очередь являются классом товара, а он у себя хранит необходимые переменные. Тогда в рамках класса можно будет создать функции которые будут фильтровать или отбирать товары по нужным категориям. Если есть вопросы, пишите)